# Replace a word (only after space or any panctuation)

Tags: javascript, regex

Replace "word" only if there is a space after it, or punctuation.

```
var s = 'a b word word. word, wordword word';
var re = new RegExp( '\\b(word)\\b ','gi');

s = s.replace(re, 'WORD ');

// current output
// "a b WORD word. word, wordword word"

// wanted:
// "a b WORD WORD. WORD, wordword word"
```

Comment: well, if you want `word.` and `word,` to be matched as well, then you should remove that space at the end of your regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a lookahead:

```
s.replace(/\bword(?=[.,;\-:\s])/gi, 'WORD')
# => "a b WORD WORD. WORD, wordword word"
```

Possibly add more punctuation. Alternatively you can use `\b`, but explicitly exclude the end of string special character. Note that this essentially your initial regex, just with the space removed (which I assume was a typo of some sorts?)

```
s.replace(/\bword\b(?!$)/gi, 'WORD')
```

Comment: helped me a lot, thanks. saved me so much time, and I also learned something new (the whole `?!` thing)